# Xcode swift remove button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I add a button like this:

```
var button: UIButton!

button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2-50, 40, 100, 50)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

And then I want to remove it with this code:

```
self.button.removeFromSuperview()
```

But it doesn't disappear. Why doesn't it disappears?

Comment: where are u calling the code ?

Comment: I am calling it in locationmanager in an if/else function

Comment: r u sure, the line gets hit ?

Comment: Yes, the line hits. but the button doesn't disappear.

Comment: Are you running on the main thread when you remove the button?

Comment: Just to eliminate the thread issue, try this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { button.removeFromSuperview() }`.

Comment: Does this code runs more than once ? Possibly it overwrites the reference of first added "button" ? So when you are removing it you have the reference of second button only and second removes with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect the button to your code by creating an IBOutlet, you can remove it from the view with:

```
button.hidden = true
```

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't remove the button from the view, it only hides it.